# Tableau which corresponds to alternating square representation

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory, young-tableaux, irreducible-representation

> Recall that $S_5$ acts on $\mathbb C^5$ by permuting its coordinates and that $\mathbb C^5$ decomposes as $V\oplus W$ where $W$ is the trivial representation and $V$ has dimension $4$. Show that the alternating square of $V$, which has dimension $6$, is irreducible. What is the tableau which corresponds to this representation?

Of course, $V$ is the natural representation and $W$ is the trivial representation. I could show that the alternating square of $V$ is irreducible. But, I don't have any idea how to find the tableau which corresponds to this representation.

As David A Craven points out, the degrees of the characters of $S_5$ are $1,1,4,4,5,5,6$. But, how does that connect with the shape of the tableau? In general, I don't know any relation between degree of a character and tableau corresponding to that character. It would help if anyone can provide any information about it.

I know the Hook Length formula in the sense that the number of standard Young tableaux of a given shape is given by $\frac{n!}{\prod h_{ij}}$ but I really don't know how to connect that to degree of representation.

Comment: What do you know? The character degrees? Hook formula? Murnaghan-Nakayama? Give us some ideas.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I know Hook Formula and I know degree of characters

Comment: So work out the degrees of $S_5$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven by _character degrees_, I guess you meant the value of the character at identity, right? How will that help to determine the tableau?

Comment: Have you tried to compute the character degrees of $S_5$ using the hook formula? that is literally the first thing you should do.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven no, I have only calculated degrees of characters when we were computing the character tables, and we didn't use the Hook Length formula then...

Comment: Go do that. You should get 1,1,4,4,5,5,6.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven yes that's exactly what I got! But, how does that connect with the shape of the tableau?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven in general, I don't know any relation between degree of a character and tableau corresponding to that character, and a quick Google search didn't give anything. Can you give me any information about it?

Comment: In what sense do you know the hook formula then?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven you are talking about the [hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula), right?

Comment: Yes. I can't see how "I don't know any relation between degree of a character and tableau corresponding to that character" and "I know Hook Formula" can both be true. I think you must have some terminology issue or something, because those are two contradictory statements.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven sorry, I may be missing something, but I know that the number of standard Young tableaux of a given shape is given by $\frac{n!}{\prod h_{ij}}$, but how does that connect with the degree of a character? Can you please elaborate a little... I am really feeling bad asking you again at this point...

Comment: @DavidA.Craven has it got anything to do with Frobenius formula? Because, I don't know that yet....

Comment: Ah. The number of standard Young tableaux is equal to the degree of the corresponding character. They label a basis for the Specht module.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven oh... so we need to find the partition of $5$, for which the number of tableaux is $6$ ($=deg(alt^2)$)?

Comment: Yes. That is right.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven thank you so much!

Comment: @DavidA.Craven you may also be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4688471/943723)...